# How to handle users spreading lots of code across multiple answers

Tags: discussion, answers

When I was reviewing I came across [this review](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/19128300). When looking a bit further I saw that this user had been posting a lot of code and images spread across multiple answers. Not only on this question but also on atleast three other questions.

This is the second time in a couple of days I say someone do this and both times I flagged it for moderation attention (But those can take some time before being handled). The first time I also downvoted the answers but that was reverted because it looked like serial voting.

How should I handle situations like this one?

Comment: You did it right by flagging a moderator.  But their flag queue is backed-up right now, that's why there is an election going on.  They'll get around to it.

Comment: At least they're helping us find ancient questions that need to be closed... >.>

Comment: @HansPassant Is there anything else I can do? Voting down the answers would have to be spread over multiple days or they will be seen as serial voting and flagging to close also seems inaffective because that queue is also backed-up (9.5K currently)

Comment: I'd personally downvote one, VLQ flag all, and since you've already got one for review, you can recommend deletion. That way, all the answers get cleaned up. The one you're referring to is already deleted, and I see a mod has deleted all the others.

Comment: The mess has been cleaned. Almost all answers were written extremely poorly - just dumping loads of code (spread across multiple answers) without any kind of explanation. You could raise a custom mod flag (just like you did) to bring such things to attention of SO mods. Unfortunately, we take some time to handle custom flags.

Comment: @TheLostMind Thank you. But is there anything more/different I can do in situations like this? Should I just wait till a mod handles it or post it here on meta for fast action? (I currently have another pending mod flag for another user with the exact same problem)

Comment: The bigger picture is that it is not spam or hate so it isn't that important that it gets insta-deleted.  As long as it happens some day, it almost always does.

Comment: Thanks for all the comments. I'm just gonna sit back and wait till the other mod flag is handled and continue reviewing and flagging like i used to do.

Comment: @AndréKool - Well, I guess raising a custom flag would be enough. Flagging those answers as VLQ might not be too useful if mods are unaware of the context. A *code only* answer is completely fine as long as it is self-explanatory :)

Comment: @TheLostMind indeed. To my understanding code only answers are not meant to be flagged in any case, if they're poor then you downvote them. But under such tags as html, css and sql code only answers are more common and perfectly acceptable.

Comment: @Gimby This: _"To my understanding code only answers are not meant to be flagged in any case"_ sounds wrong. Atleast the last part. I think VLQ or non-answers should always be flagged no matter if they are code only.

Comment: @TheLostMind I agree that code only answers can be usefull. And if you feel like doing some more work on this issue i just posted another mod flag for exactly the same reason

Comment: @AndréKool yes. Code only answers are answers and they are only low quality, not very low quality.